# Find the largest number between an array and a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have this code:

```
function LrgstNum (array){
    var max = 0;
    var a = array.length;
    var b = "";
    for (counter=0;counter<a;counter++)
    {
        if (array[counter] > max)
        {
            max = array[counter];
        }
        else if (max < b){
            max = b;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

console.log(LrgstNum([55,4,6])); // output will be 55
```

I want another string to be compared and then the max value be returned so:

```
function LrgstNum (array, str){

}
```

I want the output of `([55,4,6], 100)` to be `100`.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accept one more parameter in your function with default value and than compare your max and second parameter and return accordingly

```js
function LrgstNum (array, str = -Infinity){
    var max = 0;
    var a = array.length;
    var b = "";
    for (counter=0;counter<a;counter++)
    {
        if (array[counter] > max)
        {
            max = array[counter];
        }
        else if (max < b){
            max = b;
        }
    }
    return max > str ? max : str
}
console.log(LrgstNum([55,4,6]));
console.log(LrgstNum([55,4,6],100));
```

You can shorten your code by using [**Math.max**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

```js
const LrgstNum = (array, str = -Infinity) => Math.max(...array,str)

console.log(LrgstNum([55,4,6]));
console.log(LrgstNum([55,4,6],100));
```

**On side note:-** This assumes all your inputs are either `numbers` or `numeric strings`. if you have any case where your input case be anything else than these you need to add check for that

```js
const LrgstNum = (array, str = -Infinity) => isNaN(str) ? Math.max(...array) : Math.max(...array,str)

console.log(LrgstNum([55,4,6]));
console.log(LrgstNum([55,4,6],100));
console.log(LrgstNum([55,4,6],'Axyz'));
```

Comment: thanks a lot and also can you please explain how that works?? `return max > str ? max : str` and `str = -Infinity`

Comment: @NewUser i have added enough explanation for 1st method, and for Math.max you can see on link i have added their. if you still find any difficulty even after reading that let me know will add more explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to make it simple

```js
const arr = [55,4,6]

const arrMax = arr => arr.reduce((acc, e) => acc > e ? acc : e)

const maxBtwArrAndStr = (arr, str) => arrMax(arr) > parseInt(str) ? arrMax(arr) : parseInt(str)

console.log(arrMax(arr))
console.log(maxBtwArrAndStr(arr, "100"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler solution using Math.max()

```js
function LrgstNum(array, str) {
  // if str is defined and is numeric combine into new array, otherwise use `array` input only
  var arr = !isNaN(str) ? array.concat(str) : array
  return Math.max.apply(null, arr)
}

console.log(LrgstNum([55, 4, 6], 100))
```